# Xamarin Forms 2.3.3.175 and Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging impossible?

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin.forms, nuget

I have a Xamarin.Forms application where I want to add push notification to each platform. The Android app I want (in order to get a token) to connect to Firebase using the Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging package. I am now in the situation that I cannot add the package Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging to my Android app because of incompatible version constraint for Xamarin.Android.Support.v4. Is it really not possible to use this package in a Xamarin.Forms application?

This is my reference chain:

Android App

---  Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.175

------  Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (**= 23.3.0**)

---  Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 32.961.0

------  Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement (= 32.961.0)

---------  Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (**>= 24.2.1**)

As you see, Xamarin.Forms needs exactly 23.3.0 and the only stable Firebase needs at least 24.2.1.

Are there any other best practices how I can use Firebase / push notifications in a Xamarin.Forms app? All I actually need is a client component to get a token for the client. I have all the server side stuff deployed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not impossible, but you would need to fork the Xamarin.Forms code and change the references to the packages. This should be pretty straight forward after you have forked the [source](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms). Just modify the [forms nuspec file](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/.nuspec/Xamarin.Forms.nuspec#L20) to change the dependencies and recompile the packages.

Xamarin.Forms hard codes the references to Google Play libraries because they often introduce changes that break things in Xamarin.Forms. There is no guarantee that this will work, the new support library might break something that you are using in your application. This is the only way I know of to get things working.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but could not get the app running: MonoDroid System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000196. Looks like Xamarin.Forms cannot be used for Firebase... very strange.